# warning message while opening the excel file after export from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have written code to export data but warning message i am facing while opening the excel file and by default file is saving as .html extension

warning - "The file you are opening in a different format than specified by the file extension"

i need with .xls extension to be saved 
please help me

```
  private void ExportToExcel(DataTable dt)
  {
 string fileName = "FileName" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy_HHmmss") + ".xls";

        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);

        //Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Filename .xls");
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
        DataGrid dataExportExcel = new DataGrid();
        dataExportExcel.ItemDataBound += new DataGridItemEventHandler(dataExportExcel_ItemDataBound);
        dataExportExcel.DataSource = dt;
        dataExportExcel.DataBind();
        dataExportExcel.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
        System.Text.StringBuilder sbResponseString = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sbResponseString.Append("<html xmlns:v=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml\" xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:x=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:xlExcel8\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\"> <head></head> <body>");
        sbResponseString.Append(stringWriter + "</body></html>");
        Response.Write(sbResponseString.ToString());
        Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Omg, you are trying to create excel file and write to it Html? oO

Comment: please help me how to export to excel 
where i need to change the code

Comment: you can simply ignore the warning. I am sure the file is opening correctly on proceeding. You can also try [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/).

Comment: file opening in correct format,
but the default save is .html extension and i need as .xls extension

Answer (score 0):

Use this one - http://www.gemboxsoftware.com/spreadsheet/overview

Looks like this in use:

```
// Create new Excel file.
var excelFile = new ExcelFile();

excelFile.Worksheets.Add(dt.TableName).InsertDataTable(dt, 0, 0, true);

// Save Excel file to XLS format.
excelFile.SaveXls(dataSet.DataSetName + ".xls");
```

Comment: No maris.. i am not supposed to add external Dll's